# Why is my Rebel XTi taking blurry photos?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, blur

I noticed how my Canon Rebel XTi started to take blurry photos. My pictures aren't as sharp as before. I am using the same settings as I did when it took perfect pictures. What could be wrong with the camera? I've tried messing with the settings and changing the lens with no luck. Has anyone else had this same problem with this camera?

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but if you don't post a photo with the full EXIF information there is not much that we can do to assist. Since you have limited reputation here; you likely have to post a link to the image hosted elsewhere. Flickr or Google Picasa Web Images should work just fine. At the absolute minimum, please describe the shot and settings(i.e. picture of a running football player under dark nightime lighting, taken in A mode at f/5.6, 1/15sec, ISO 800.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have already but check that the AF/MF switch on the lens is set to AF (auto focus), and also check the focus points that you're using: when you press the capture button half way for focus and metering, the camera should make some of the autofocus points flash red to show which it's focusing on. If it's always using the same one, then you may need to change this so it uses all of them, but from memory this might only apply if you're using M, Av or Tv modes.

I think the right hand button on the camera back (a box with a cross of points in) allows you to scroll through the focus points with the wheel when you're looking through the viewfinder. When all of them are lit, it will choose the AF point automatically. But note that I think this is only applicable in the shooting modes I mentioned above

Comment: The point selection also applies in P mode if memory serves, though it has been a while since I used my xti.

Comment: @AJHenderson quite possibly, I usually only shoot manual so I'm actually fairly unfamiliar with all the other modes!

Comment: If it has a P mode I know it supports point selection there. I just can't remember for certain if it does. I'm pretty sure it did but I've worked with enough gear that some settings get crossed in my head.